# Selecting entries that appear in two places

Tags: sql, select

Here is the schema:

```
CREATE TABLE AUTHOR (
    AID char(9), 
    Aname VARCHAR(10), 
    Occupation VARCHAR(10), 
    PRIMARY KEY(AID)
);

CREATE TABLE Book (
    ISBN CHAR(7), 
    Year NUMBER(4), 
    Title VARCHAR(20), 
    PRIMARY KEY(ISBN)
);

CREATE TABLE Paper (
    PID CHAR(4), 
    Title VARCHAR(20), 
    ISBN CHAR(7), 
    PRIMARY KEY (PID), 
    FOREIGNN KEY (ISBN) REFERENCES BOOK
);

CREATE TABLE WRITES (
    AID CHAR(9), 
    PID CHAR(4), 
    PRIMARY KEY (AD,PID), 
    FOREIGN KEY (AID) REFERENCES Author, 
    FOREIGN KEY(PID) REFERENCES Paper
);
```

In order to find the names of authors whose papers appeared in both books "Artificial Intelligence" and "Generic Algorithms", what SQL query should I execute?

Comment: Is this a question in a quiz or something?

Comment: It's a practice question on SQL. I didn't know the answer, so decided to ask and learn. Wasn't really trying to plagiarise on any school assignments/quizzes.

Comment: That's good. Sorry I didn't mean it to demotivate. Keep Querying!

Comment: That's alright. Many thanks Maheswaran!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Think in sets. You are looking for the authors that are in the set of authors of papers in book A AND in the set of authors of papers in book B:

```
select * from author
where aid in
(
  select aid from writes where pid in
  (
    select pid from paper where isbn in
    (
      select isbn from book where title = 'Artificial Intelligence'
    )
  )
)
and aid in
(
  select aid from writes where pid in
  (
    select pid from paper where isbn in
    (
      select isbn from book where title = 'Generic Algorithms'
    )
  )
);
```

Comment: Many thanks. Wish I had enough reputation to vote up.

Comment: When the Book title input increases, it creates an overhead in framing the query and also performance, Considering large volume of data.

Comment: Well, the statement is very fast using indexes everywhere. Only when you expect a large percentage of authors to be found, this wouldn't make sense anymore. And yes, it would look a bit clumsy, when used for more books :-) As you already said in your answer: There are many ways to write the query.